# Getting Doctrine's findAll() to include assosiations from link table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Background**

I have a `Discipline` and a `Playlist` class.

- A discipline can have zero to many playlists
- A playlist can only be associated with one discipline

In my Controller, I have

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('NodeBundle:Discipline');
$disciplines = $repository->findAll();
```

My `discipline` and `playlist` tables are pretty straightforward, but then there's a `discipline_playlist` link table, with `id`, `discipline_id (FK)`, and `playlist_id (FK)`.

**Problem**

What I'd like is for Doctrine to give me the Discipline objects, complete with an Array/Collection of Playlist objects.

Can this be achieved using Doctrine alone, or do I need to fetch the Playlists separately, and link them together in my controller (PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

So if i do understand you there is a ***many-to-many relationship*** between discipline and playlist. Then Doctrine can make the join-table for you automatically. You don't need to make it yourself and also you don't need a primary id column. (You never need an id column on a join-table).

Check this [example](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) but change all annotations by inserting the letters **ORM\** after the @ so that they will start with @ORM\ .

Comment: I tried doing exactly that, but when I fetch disciplines, the $playlists variable is an empty array even though I have relevant entries in the link table.

Comment: Actually, it turns out it was there, but lazy loaded (I think), so I wasn't able to see it.

Comment: Yes doctrines array collection is lazy loaded.

Comment: Do you know if I can force load child elements before I pass it to the template?

Comment: Will be posible but the lazy loading is not without reason. It also decreases memory usage by avoiding loading huge numbers of records in one time. If you are sure that there will be only a acceptabele amount of data you could consider to use a normal array . I dont know how to load all data in one time but there will be online docs that can help you